# How to create a large graph with igraph (10^5 vertices and 4*10^6 edges) in Python?

Tags: python, database, graph, bigdata, igraph

I have been trying to build a `graph` in `Igraph` with the size of `10^6` vertices and `4*10^6`. I have listed my attempts and methods below:

1. using `add_edge`. Obviously, this does not work because `Igraph` has to recreate the index for edge too many times.
2. using `add_edges`. It is still too slow and my process is killed automatically
3. using `Graph` `constructor`. So now my code becomes like this:

`Graph(n=self._n,edges=self._edges,directed=True,graph_attrs=self._graph_attrs,vertex_attrs=self._vertex_attrs,edge_attrs=self._edge_attrs)`

I have been looking around on how to improve this but my process is always killed and it takes very long time. Any suggestion?

Moreover, if I want to use iGraph with database, which database should I use?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `add_edges` should work if the constructor call works - they are doing the same thing (the constructor just calls `add_edges`). One possible problem is that the vertex IDs you are using in the edge list are not consecutive integers from 0 to |V|-1, so igraph ends up creating many isolated vertices just because it sees a vertex with a very high ID.

Comment: Would you be willing to try networkx instead?  I expect it should be straightforward with networkx as long as you've got the memory.  That said, it doesn't make sense to me that there's a problem with igraph.